# Proof that $2^{222}-1$ is divisible by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove that $2^{222}-1$ is divisible by three? 
I already have decomposed the following one: $(2^{111}-1)(2^{111}+1)$ and I understand I should just prove that $(2^{111}-1)$ is divisible by three or that $(2^{111}+1)$ is divisible by three. But how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The Maple code $2^{222}-1 \mod 3$ outputs $0$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The routine way is to invoke [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem): $$a^{p-1}-1\equiv 0\,(\text{mod}\,p)$$ for $\mathrm{gcd}(a,p)=1$.
Plug in $a=2^{111},p=3$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the link. Actually you help me very much. Thanks!!

Answer (score 54):

The three numbers $2^{111}-1$, $2^{111}$ and $2^{111}+1$ are consecutive, and so one of them is divisible by $3$. But $2^{111}$ is not, since $2$ is prime.

Answer (score 26):

**HINT**

If you're familiar with binomial theorem $$\color{blue}{2^{222}}-1 = \color{blue}{(3-1)^{222}}-1 = \color{blue}{1+3M} -1 = \color{blue}{3M}$$

Comment: thanks to you, now I've just discovered it for myself

Comment: You know... I read about binomial theorem, but actually it looks like not the same as your... it's not like what you wrote here. What is M? Can you give me a useful link with explanation or something like of if you don't mind?

Comment: Ahh okay good, here $M$ is some integer. Expand $(3-1)^{222}$ using binomial theorem and soon you will notice that all the terms are multiples of $3$ except the last term which would be $1$. $$\color{blue}{(3-1)^{222} = \binom{222}{0}3^{222} - \binom{222}{1}3^{221} + \cdots + \binom{222}{220}3^2 -\binom{222}{221}3^1 + \binom{222}{222}3^0 = 3M + 1}$$

Comment: You might find below results based on binomial thm interesting $$(x+1)^n = Mx + 1\\ (x-1)^n = Mx + (-1)^n\\(x+a)^n = Mx + a^n$$

Comment: Alternatively (this is really the same proof but hiding the binomial stuff), since $2\equiv-1$ also $2^{222}\equiv(-1)^{222}=1$.

Comment: Okay,Ganeshie, I figured out this thing. binomial theorem perfectly well works thanks to You very much for an additional explanation of this point

Answer (score 10):

When $n$ is odd we have that $$a^n+1=(a+1)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}+a^{n-3}-\cdots-a+1)$$
Plugging in $a=2$ you see that the expression is divisible by 3

Comment: I'm thankful for your one. Thanks, it's seemed to be the most readable and understandable for me and for anyone else

Answer (score 5):

You can use coungrence 
$$2 \equiv 2 \;(\bmod\; 3)$$
$$2^2 \equiv 4 \equiv 1 \;(\bmod\; 3)$$
$$2^3 \equiv 8 \equiv 2 \;(\bmod\; 3)$$

It is easy to conclude (and prove) that:
$$2^{2k} \equiv 1 (\bmod\; 3)$$
$$2^{2k+1} \equiv 2 \;(\bmod\; 3)$$

So $$2^{222} \equiv 1  \;(\bmod\;3)$$
and 
$$2^{222} - 1\equiv 1 - 1 \equiv 0  \;(\bmod\;3)$$

Comment: This all is seemed to be number theory... I don't really know it well I've never faced it directly. But your explanation is very interesting, so thank you a lot for this

Answer (score 4):

${\rm mod}\,\ 3\!:\ \color{#c00}{2^2\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,2^{J+2K}\equiv 2^J\color{#3c00}{(\color{#c00}{2^2})}^K\equiv 2^J\color{#c00}{1}^K\equiv 2^J.\,$ Yours is $\,J=0,\,K=111$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally $\ \color{}{a\equiv -1}\Rightarrow\, a^{J+2K}\equiv a^J\,$ by $\,(-1)^{2K}\equiv 1,\,$ as above

Above we used standard [Congruence Arithmetic Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) (Product and Power Rules).

This exploitation of periodicity of powers generalizes from squares to any power, namely

**Key Idea** $ $ Generally, if $\,a^e\equiv 1\pmod m\,$ then exponents on $\,a\,$ can be taken mod $\,e,\,$ i.e. $\ a^{\large j}\equiv a^{\large k}\pmod m\,\ $ if $\,\ j\equiv k\pmod e.\ $ This may be proved exactly as above, i.e.

$$ \begin{array}{}\color{#c00}{a^{\large e}\equiv 1}\\ j = k\! +\! en\end{array}\Rightarrow\,\ a^{\large j}\equiv a^{\large  k+en}\equiv a^{\large  k}\color{#c00}{(a^{\large  e})}^{\large  n}\equiv a^{\large  k}\color{#c00}{(1)}^{\large  n}\equiv a^k\!\!\pmod m\qquad $$

So, in your case $\ {\rm mod}\ 3\!:\,\ 2^{\large \color{#b0f}2}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{\large 2N}\equiv 2^{\large 2N\ {\rm mod}\, \color{#b0f}2}\equiv 2^0\equiv 1$

Comment: I'm a bit confused seeing this. But I'm grateful for your explanation

Comment: @Klochkovskiy Let me know what proves confusing so I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to compute the powers of 2 modulo 3: 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, ...

Clearly $2^n \equiv 2 \bmod 3$ if $n$ is odd and $2^n \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ if $n$ is even.

So, if $n$ is even ($n = 222$ certainly qualifies), then $2^n - 1 \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ as asserted.